# Many to many polymorphic table in hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to implement a many to many polymorphic association in hibernate.

I have an interface `Animal` and two implementing classes `Cat` and `Dog`. I have another class Food and I'm looking to connect the Animal interface to the food class  through a database many to many relationship. I'm trying to understand how to map it through a polymorphic association like the Ruby on Rails implementation.

The many to many association should look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|   food_id   |   animal_type   |   animal_id   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I've been working on this for a while and I'm not sure how to implement this in hibernate.

Answer (score -3):

It's not terribly clear what you want your database mapping to model, but usually Hibernate mapping models reality so I'll assume a food is eaten by MANY animals and and animal eats MANY foods.
In this case you'll need a linking table in your database FOOD_ANIMAL which contains food_id and animal_id:

FOOD_ANIMAL:
food_id  int(11), animal_id  int(11)

You'll then need a List<> or Set<> of food's in animal and vice versa. Use @ManyToMany for your mapping. There's a wealth of examples on how to do this, such as:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

I'm afraid I can't help much more without code examples, but I hope this helps!

Comment: That would be a simple - many to many - table... I'm looking for something a bit more complex... since animal is an interface there is no unique id for an animal, instead the class name and the id of that specific animal type act as a multi-key...

Comment: Your interface shouldn't model the object itself. You use hibernate to map your table (containing a unique ID) of animals with a model in Java using @table, and the standard is for your interface to be used as a data access object for updating your database using hibernate. I'd recommend using the standard pattern for your situation because it's a simple m-to-m relationship.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that if i decide tomorrow to create a Pet interface where i put Cat, Dog and Rock (which is not of the animal interface), they all animals and pets would have to share an id sequence... then later when i decide to add another interface named Thing which i have Rock, Elevator and Motorcycle they will also have to be under the same id sequence since Dog must have the same id sequence as rock and rock must have the same id as motorcycle... and we can add more and more examples to this. The question was specific, How can i create that type of Poly Association...